# Simulation using the fundamental theorem of simulation (MATLAB)

Tags: inference, bootstrap, simulation, matlab, computational-statistics

I have a sub-task of an assignment about the parametric bootstrap method. The subtask is to, given a *students t-distribution* with $5$ degrees of freedom, sample $10000$ draws using the fundamental theorem of simulation. The algorithm is:

[image: Fundamental theorem of simulation]

Then, I should produce a histogram of the simulated data and compare it to the exact pdf for *the students t-distribution* with $5$ degrees of freedom.

My plot "looks" like it has the same distribution but is seems as though it is not right somehow. I´ve inserted my code below for the algorithm, so feel free to comment if I´ve missed a crucial part or misunderstood something!

I guess the goal is to be able to use the histogram as approximation of the integral, but that doesn´t seem to work out for me.

I´ve tried to add more draws but that doesn´t seem to make the histogram any better at approximating the integral, it just adds more "bars" to the histogram. Is it just a scaling/normalizing problem in my code somehow or is there anything else I´m missing?

**MATLAB CODE:**

```
% Let X be the support of the tpdf, the support is thoeretically the set of
% all real numbers, for for this assignment, we let the support be the
% interval [a,b] as the absolute values of the y-values outside this interval gets very small.
a = -4;
b = 4;

% Plots the true tpdf to see where a possible max M is
X = linspace(a,b);
Y = tpdf(X,5);
plot(X,Y) % 0.4 will for as a max for the simulation
hold on

% max := M <= 0.4
M = 0.4;

% Number of draws
d = 10000;

% Matrix for storing accepted points under the curve
acc = NaN(d,1);

rng(1)
% We now want to sample d draws using the fundamental theorem of simulation
for k=1:d
    u1_star = unifrnd(a,b);
    f = tpdf(u1_star,5);
    u2_star = unifrnd(0.0,M);
    if (u2_star < f)
        acc(k,1) = u1_star;
    end
end

acc;
histogram(acc,"Normalization","pdf")
```

[image]

Comment: What are the bars intended to depict?  They aren't a histogram, because their total area is approximately 0.1 (height) times 0.6 (base, approximately) times 1/2 (formula for a triangle), which is obviously far less than 1 as required by any valid histogram.

Comment: I will edit the code or answer my own Q, I seem to have solved the issue!

Comment: Also, how do you draw samples from a uniform distribution on the support of a Cauchy distribution?  There doesn't exist such a thing.  And more: what does any of this have to do with a parametric bootstrap?

Comment: I don´t understand your first question. For the second one: It is just a sub-task to learn the method written above. In the next task, I will use this algorithm to produce bootstrap data. This specific problem had nothing specifically to do with the bootstrap method. I never claimed that either other than in the "tags".

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue I had. I substituted the for-loop with this code section below and it produced the histogram/integral-plot i wanted!

The problem was, I believe, that I did not have enough points e.i. 10000 "accepted" draws because the for-loop only did 10000 iterations and rejeted most of them and had mostly NaNs, but I wanted 10000 "accepted" draws, so I did the whole thing using a while-loop that keeps on iterating until the length of the vector acc is of the right length.

```
% We now want to sample d draws using the fundamental theorem of simulation
acc = NaN(1,1); % Creates a vector that we can concatenate with "accepted" draws with
% This while loop concatenates the d points with the NaN-vector to create a vector with accepted draws of length 10001
while length(acc) < d+1
    u1_star = unifrnd(a,b);
    f = tpdf(u1_star,5);
    u2_star = unifrnd(0.0,M);
    if (u2_star < f)
        acc = [acc u1_star];
    end
end
```

[image]